# Повторное навешивание обработчиков

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. есть у меня метод loadPage:

```
$('body').load(url)
```

проблема в том, что js файлы загружаются заново и навешивают обработчики событий несколько раз. Этот метод служит для выхода/входа, соответственно, сколько раз пользователь выйдет/зайдет, столько раз навесятся одни одни и те же обработчики. Можно сделать придумать что-нибудь?

Comment: Может просто вынести javascript обработчики в тег head?

Answer (score 1):

load поддерживает загрузку выбранного элемента из загруженной страницы:

> However, in the following case, script blocks in the document being loaded into #b are stripped out and not executed:
>
> 1 $( "#b" ).load( "article.html #target" );

Как написано выше, в этом случае скрипты исполняться не будут ([doc](http://api.jquery.com/load/)). Таким образом, можно просто повесить на body один якорь для всех страниц и использовать его таким образом.

Если вышеописанное - не вариант, то можно просто ставить обработчики по условию отсутствия какого-то GET-параметра: если его нет, то все обработчики ставятся, если он есть, то обработчики не ставятся. После этого к url надо будет добавить что-нибудь вроде ?ajax=true или &ajax=true к url при запросе функции.

"По-хорошему" ваш сервис в ответ на аякс-запрос должен предоставлять либо кусок html, а не всю страницу, либо json-ответ.